# Что использовать для инфографики по коктейлям

Tags: jquery, svg, canvas, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Хочу сделать наглядное представление рецептуры коктейлей в браузере. Посоветуйте что лучше использовать. Выбор стоит:
SVG/
Верстать дивами/
Canvas
Приоритет там где проще :)
[вот пример](http://home-bar.ru/kak-sdelat-idealnyi-kokteil-infografika)

Comment: [d3](http://d3js.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотек много на самом деле.

Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/hgFvQ/1/) на [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com)

```
var paper = Raphael('holder', 640, 480);

var elem = paper.rect(245, 20, 200, 23);
paper.text(400, 30, 'Воздух');

var elem = paper.rect(245, 46, 200, 110);
paper.text(400, 95, 'Водка');

paper.image('http://upyourpic.org/images/201310/mka62xi6b8.png', 100, 0, 300, 300);
```